# How to set UIImageView by code?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

**Image view**
I want to set image on uiimage view by coding, i am using below code but image is not showing in my image view.

```
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"abc.png"];
      [imageView setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"abc.png"];
```

use either

```
  [_imageView setImage:image];
```

or

```
 [self.imageView setImage:image];
```

and please check whether synthesize or not  if you are synthesized Image view then no need to add _ or self.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have found the answer, I would like to mention 2 possible reason for this

1> there is no image name abc in your application bundle (could be spelling mistake also)

2> or imageView is nil as in your case

3> or imageView's frame not fit in parent view's bound

4> or imageView is not added as subview in your view

Comment: Sorry its my mistake, I didn'd create outlet for the imageview so that the image was not displayed, Code is fine, There is no problem